# From one random value, can one know the next or previous, especially using javascript getRandomValues()?

Tags: javascript, random, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I have an application where I generate a username & a password for each user.

Since these two are **generated directly after each other**, can an attacker **know the password from the username**?

I'm asking because the username & password are not actually random -- they're just **2 consecutive elements in the same PRNG sequence**. So, what guarantees do we have about this sequence regarding knowing future or past elements by knowing some consecutive elements of it?

The question can be answered for [Crypto.getRandomValues()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) or pseudo-random generators. I.e., is there a requirement on PRNG sequence of not being able to tell future elements even if you know some consecutive elements?

Example: How many consecutive elements of Math.Random() do you need to know to be able to predict the next one? ... because [its implementation is simpler](https://v8.dev/blog/math-random), and if it's hard for it it *should* be harder for Crypto.getRandomValues().

Comment: Yes, the requirement is called a CSPRNG. Crypto.getRandomValues() is a CSPRNG, Math.random() is a _mere_ PRNG. If you want additional guarantees, mix in an unknown along with your random value, like a salt or password  with the number to get a new number, using a hash or KDF. To reverse, the attacker would need to know the extra value, even if they could predict the PRNG output, which itself is far from trivial these days, especially the past few years as awareness has increased.

Comment: CSPRNG simply means that you cannot predict future outputs based on past results, whereas a lot of PRNGs are 100% deterministic.

Comment: you could also simply shuffle the rows to breakup the order if in doubt.

Comment: Thank you @dandavis , CSPRNG seems to be the answer. For your other points, I prefer not to do my own cryptography schemes -- "If I roll my own, I'm wrong" :-), but thank you for the suggestions :). And what do you mean with "shuffle the rows"? what rows?

Comment: @dandavis Could you write an answer around your comments?